# Como poner el marcador en mi ubicación como esta en la imagen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Cordial saludo apenas estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación. como puedo hacer para poner un marcador como esta en la imagen en la ubicación que yo cree mil gracias.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: podrías indicarnos un poquito más sobre que quieres conseguir ? debe ser dinámico o es solo mostrar el mapa tal cual. Ya que si copias la URL que te proporciona el maps y la pegas en un iframe tendrás el mapa tal y como lo estés viendo en ese momento.

Comment: Buenas tardes Angel Fraga en la ubicación donde esta el numero 5, yo quiero que cuando le den click aparezca un cuadro igual como el de la panadería en la imagen se puede observar que cuando se le da click aparece un cuadro con los datos quisiera un ejemplo fácil de entender por que los de Internet casi no los entiendo mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

lo que quieres se encuentra en "**Ventanas de información**" (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows?hl=es-419), el código es:

```
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que en google map aparezca una etiqueta de este tipo , hay dos formas una en el mapa general y otra en un mapa personalizado que debes programar.

En la primera que supongo que es la que quieres debes de dar de alta a tu empresa/oficina/colegio ... en google maps.

Para ello entra en https://www.google.com/intl/es-419_us/business/ y crea la ficha del negocio. Te enviaran un código a la dirección indicada que deberás introducir en la  URL indicada. Con este paso verificas la existencia de la empresa , y podrás compartir el mapa con la etiqueta, por ejemplo en tu web.

Si lo que necesitas es crear un mapa personalizado google maps también te da esta opción , entra en https://www.google.com/maps/d/ cuando hallas iniciado sesión en gmail y podrás crear tu mapa. Un ejemplo del editor sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves puedes añadir sitios , editar el titulo de la etiqueta , agregarle tu propia descripción ...

Si le das a vista previa del mapa , podrás compartirlo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo la opción de insertar código la que te da el codigo HTML necesario para incrustarlo a tu web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe anotar que puedes crear tus propios puntos de interés

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esto te queda pequeño porque lo que necesitas es hacerlo dinámico, entonces creo que tu solución sería hacerlo con las APIs de google , la cual tienen documentación en español https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=es-419